# How to find a Cepheid's pulsation period using its graph?

Tags: distances, luminosity, cepheids, absolute-magnitude, variable-star

Basically, I've been seeing these graphs that say: Cepheid Period-Luminosity Relation and the Period axis is supposed to be "logarithmic";

How does this graph work? Since the luminosity of a star doesn't just increase, as we know, but it increases and decreases periodically, why does the magnitude keep raising?
How do I find the pulsating period of such a star through a graph like this?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This graph is not the light curve of a cepheid. It is used to find the average brightness of the star, and from that, estimate its distance.

The rate at which cepheids pulse is related to their *average* luminosity (and so their average absolute magnitude). This graph relates the period to their average absolute magnitude.

To use the graph, observe a cepheid for long enough to establish a period (say 30 days, for example). Then read the graph (an absolute magnitude of just under -5.5 in the example)

You now know how intrinsically bright the star is on average. By looking at its average apparent brightness, you can calculate an estimate of its distance. See [How does the cepheid variables help in finding distance](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/17826/how-does-the-cepheid-variables-help-in-finding-distance?rq=1)